# how to back to root view controller even if I am in another tab in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

let say I have 3 main tabs in bottom navigation called

1. Home
2. Search
3. Profile

if I am in Home tab, I then can go to Product List VC and Product Detail VC like this

Home --> Product List --> Product Detail

let say after in product detail VC (in Home Tab), the user then select profile tab to perform log out action

I want when the user log out, all tabs should be in the root, I mean in the top hierarchy of each tab, not inside like product detail

I know that I can back to root VC using this code below if I am in the same tab:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

but I what I want is, even if I am in profile tab, I can make other tab (home and search) back to root view controller.

how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first: Home, Search, Profile must be UINavigationController.
and when user logout at Profile viewcontroller, call:

```
if let navigations = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers {
            for item in navigations {
                if let navigation = item as? UINavigationController {
                    navigation.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` for all controllers of tabbar. Hence you have to do this,

```
    tabBarController.viewControllers?.forEach({ (vc) in
       if let navigationController = vc as? UINavigationController {
            navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you -

```
tabBarController.viewControllers?.forEach({ (vc) in

   if let navigationController = vc as? UINavigationController {

       if let rootVC =  navigationController.viewControllers[0] {

             navigationController.viewControllers = [rootVC]
        }
   }
})
```

to get your `tabBarController` at any point (I am assuming you have a navigation controller at root on each tab) -

```
 if let tabBarController = self.navigationController?.parent as? UITabBarController {
      //use tab bar controller here
 }
```